# Automating text entry for duplicate values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have a sheet with a unique ID number in A for each booking which are be duplicated in the list (based on arriving/departure) - I am filling out Column D with another value for each booking. Is there a formula I can use whereby if I enter a unique value into Column D, it will auto populate for the other entries of the unique ID in Column A?

eg.

| ID No. | Conf. No. |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 00001 |
| 54321 | 00002 |
| 12345 | 00001 |
| 54321 | 00002 |

Duplicate value formulas I've found so far just enter 'DUPLICATE' into the column or highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

[image]

Used iferror() so if there is no match then blank, edit ranges to suit.